# why PIL is not installing in python version 3.9.7

Tags: python

I have facing the issue  I could not import PIL in VS code.but in jupyter notebook it is imported.my python version is python 3.9.7 ,i have tried many commands to install but its not work.it keep saying like no module named as PIL .and also I couldnot import requests also in vs code.I used these commands
pip install PIL
pip install Pillow
but it didnot work

Comment: Could you provide us with an output of the error message or in general more details on what you already did?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.